# Autoload a popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, popup

I need a solution to automatically load popups using jQuery or simply javascript.

I tried to use it on 'body onload'

Please Help me.
Thanks in advance.
Sreejith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question  is not clear , but you can use jquery document ready to do all load type events its equvalent to body onload

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   call your popup show here//
});
```

let me know if you need anything else

jquery ui dialog is pretty good for

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
```

you can write your own html and give a better z-index and do a .show on the document ready

one more plugin for buble popups

```
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqBubblePopup
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can use .ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Whatever action to run on page load
});
```